Change the name of .htaccess file to something else
Is .htaccess like a keyword? I want to name my htaccess file something else like foo.bar instead of having .htaccess as the file name. Is that possible ? Why should htaccess file be named .htaccess and not anything else. Is this written somewhere in the docs? Is there a way to make some one file act as my htaccess file?

From the docs:

If you want to call your .htaccess file something else, you can change the name of the file using the AccessFileName directive. For example, if you would rather call the file .config then you can put the following in your server configuration file:
AccessFileName ".config"


